# (node:25642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:50218

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

Coming from Selenium and Python im trying to learn JS now.  When I run the following code below:

```
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

driver.get('http://google.com');

driver.quit();
```

I get the error:

***(node:25717) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection***

It seems related to the ***driver.quit();*** line because when I remove it, I get no error.

Thanks,

Comment: `driver.get('http://google.com');` should wait until it loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error due to you `quit` before it loaded. So, we can simply wait for `driver.get` until it done before quit

```js
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async () => {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('http://google.com');
    await driver.quit();
})();
```